# Yii2 - orFilterWhere with and array

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a line like this:

```
->orFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'LOWER(components.no_cas)', $cas])
```

**$cas** is array with 1 to n elements, and at the moment the search is not working properly. Is there a way to use **orFilterWhere** with an array, or I have to use **foreach** loop?

Comment: try this :->orFilterWhere(['IN', 'LOWER(components.no_cas)', $cas])

Answer (score 1):

If it is in ModelSearch - yes, just try to add

```
$query:->orFilterWhere(['Like', 'LOWER(components.no_cas)', this->$cas])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->andFilterWhere(['or like', 'LOWER(components.no_cas)', $cas])
```